# Pass the same icon through owner to all ShowDialogs

Tags: vb.net, winforms, icons

So I have this function that all my forms use. In this function I set the current form to set a certain icon.

This goes perfectly fine.

But I have no idea how to pass this icon from the "owner" to all the ShowDialog(Me).

Is there a method I could use that just takes over the owners icon? Or does someone have another way for the next time I have to change like 50 showdialogs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inherit your dialogs from a base class, you could override the ShowDialog(parent) method to assign the parent's icon to the dialog.